# Regular Expression for not allowing 'Space in start and ending of string' and Special Characters in a string?

Tags: javascript

I am using the following regex but it is not working..

> var patt1 = "/^\s*$/";

Comment: why not just `trim()` the string?

Comment: I need to check both "white spaces" and "special characters" at a time.What should I do?

Comment: Please provide more detail on what you are trying to achieve @Tink.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With regex you could:

- match a string that starts or ends with spaces: `/^\s.*\s$/`
- match a string that does not start or end with spaces: `/^[^\s].*[^\s]$/`
- extract the string between the spaces: `/^\s(.*)\s$/`

So with regex you could define, what you accept (with exception), but not explicitly deny.

So either you match strings, that start and end with unallowed characters, for example:

- `/^\s.*\s$/` (only spaces)
- `/^[^0-9a-zA-Z].*[^0-9a-zA-Z]$/` (all non-alphanumeric character)

Or you accept strings, that *do not* start or end with an unallowed characters, for example:

- `/^[0-9a-zA-Z]+$/` only alphanumeric cha
- `/^[^\s]+$/` everything but spaces allowed

Answer (score 0):

(^\s+) will find all spaces at the start

(\s+$) will find all spaces at the end.

Special characters depend on what exactly you want to get rid of, but this will select all non alphanumeric characters [^0-9a-zA-Z]

Comment: `[0-9a-zA-Z]` — please keep in mind that there are more than one language on the planet.

Comment: Yes, but the OP didn't specify any other language, and POSIX describes alphanumeric as I did.

Comment: yes, sure, not to bash on your answer, but worth a mention in my opinion :)